# Construct a fair game with a $N$ sided die

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, puzzle

You have a $N$ sided die. And $X$ players. You have to devise a game, such that only one player wins and every player is equally likely to win.
Also, the game should be finite (there shouldn't be a single infinite run in the sample space)

Is it possible to construct such a game? (However complicated, doesn't matter) If yes, how?

At the first glance, it seems like it isn't possible, since (For $N=6$) we can only have sample space of the sizes of powers of $2,3,6$. But maybe there exists a complicated game where the sizes are different?

Comment: I don't see how it is possible to ensure *finiteness*.  For any game you devise, there is a chance the die rolls:  11111111111111.... or whichever number does not decide the game.  Right?  Oh:  is $X \leq N$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $X$ and $N$ can be any numbers. And by finiteness I mean that you need to ensure that the game always ends. One example would be: Roll the die once, and decide the winner just based on that. But it is obviously not a fair game in general. (If a number doesn't decide the game, then that game simply doesn't work for my question)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork If there exists $k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that $X = N^k,$ then the game is decidable in a finite number of steps.  Randomly assign seed numbers $\{1,2,\cdots, X\}$, and on each round, divide the remaining players into groups of $N$ each.  With each group, roll the die once, to see who from a particular group advances to the next round.  Since $X = N^k$, and since each round is dividing the numbers remaining by $N$ no one gets a bye, so the strategy works.

Comment: The *begged* question is whether, at any stage of the tournament, there is a way of using an $N$ sided die to randomly select a number from $r$ groups, where $r$ is **not** a divisor of $n$.  Frankly, I don't see how it would be possible, if $r$ is not a divisor of $n$.

Comment: @user2661923:  The whole difficulty, expressed by the OP himself, is for *other* sample sizes.  Your whole answer hangs on your initial "*if*"... but there is no reason to be certain that holds.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I completely agree with you.  In fact, the only relevance of my comments is whether they may be used to exactly specify when the constraints may be unsolvable.  Based on all of the responses, while I suspect that the problem is only solvable if $X = r^k, r|N$, I do not see any easy way of proving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the game is always finite, let $K$ be the maximum length of the game. We have $N^K$ possible outcomes for $K$ rolls, so the game must assign each player the same number of these outcomes, i.e. $X$ must divide $N^K$.

Now how do we translate the existence of such $K$ to a condition on $N$ and $X$? If $X=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_l^{k_l}$ (all $k_i>0$), then such $K$ exist if and only if $p_1p_2\ldots p_l$ divides $N$ ($N$ must divide all prime factors of $X$, because otherwise $N^K$ can never be a multiple of $X$). This is sufficient because if we set $K=\text{lcm}(k_1,\ldots,k_l)$, then $X$ divides $N^K$.

We conclude: If $X=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\ldots p_l^{k_l}$ (the prime factorisation of $X$), then a fair finite game exists if and only if  $p_1p_2\ldots p_l$ divides $N$.

EDIT:

As an example, let us construct a game when $X=20$ and $N=10$: Note that $X=2^2\cdot 5$, so the condition '$p_1p_2\ldots p_l$ divides $N$' becomes $2\cdot 5=10$ divides $N$, which holds for $N=10$. I claim that we can make the game always have 2 rolls. Also, instead of $\{1,\ldots, 10\}$, I will label the outcome of the dice as $\{0,1,\ldots, 9\}$. 2 rolls now look like (5,1), (0,9), (8,7) and so on. Notice that these look like 2 digit numbers, so you see rolling a (0,9) as the number 9 for example. Given that we have 20 players, we can simply divide the 100 possible outcomes (0 to 99) among the players, so each player gets 5 outcomes as their win condition.

Player 1 wins if the 'outcome' is less than 5, i.e. the rolls were (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3) and (0,4). Player 2 wins if the outcome is between 5 and 10: (0,5),(0,6),(0,7),(0,8) and (0,9). And so on

Comment: +1 : Very nice analysis.

Comment: The type of games you have considered is simply where there are $K$ rolls. Now consider this: If on the first roll, the number is more than, say $3$, then we roll again, otherwise some player wins. Then the possible outcomes are not of the form you mentioned. What I want to say is that your analysis doesn't rule out all types of games. Nice analysis for the sufficiency though.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal No, if there is a finite number of at most  K rolls then it is covered by this analysis because it can be transformed to a game with exactly K rolls. Simply do K rolls and for each sequence of K rolls decide who has won. If a user has won already after the first roll, as you described in your example, then he has won all sequences that start with this winning first roll.

Comment: I am sure that X|N^K is necessary and I think it is sufficient.

Comment: @AntonV. "a fair finite game exists if and only if $N$ divides $p_1p_2\ldots p_l$" This  seems strange.  Do you want to say $p_1p_2\ldots p_l$ divides $N$?

Comment: @miracle173 I'm sorry, I've indeed switched the order of the two.

Comment: Got the point. The key here is realising what @miracle173 pointed out. Every finite game can be transformed. Thanks all!

Comment: $K$ only needs to be $max(k_i)$, not $lcm(k_i)$ because $p_i^{k_i}$ is a factor of $p_i^K$ whenever $K\ge k_i$

Comment: $X|N^K$ is necessary and sufficient. I think this should be clearly stated in the post. "N  must divide all prime factors of X," What does this mean? "Each prime factor of $X$ must divide $N$" is the correct statement.

Comment: if If $N=p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2}\cdots p_l^{t_l}$ then the smallest $K$ is  $\left\lceil\max\left\{0, \frac {p_1^{k_1}} {p_1^{t_1}},  \frac {p_2^{k_2}} {p_2^{t_2}},\cdots, \frac {p_l^{k_l}} {p_l^{t_l}}\right\}\right\rceil$

Answer (score 2):

There exists a fair finite game if $X = N^k, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ ending in precisely $k$ rolls of the die (simply enumerate the $X$ players in base $N$) or if $N = kX, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ ending in a single roll of the die (enumerate die sides modulo $X$). Otherwise, David Stork's comment applies, though it's not necessarily the case that any particular side of the die will not determine the game (non-terminal conditions can be arbitrarily complicated).

In the interest of answering your question properly, I'll give an example where no such game may be constructed: $X > 1, N = 1$. Any game is deterministic so that only one player can win.

In order for the game to end, there must in general be a terminal condition. This can be in the form of a limit on how many rolls of the die are to be made or in the form of some terminating pattern occurring in the string of rolls. If there is no upper bound on the number of rolls to be made, then there is some pattern which does not terminate the game in any particular number of moves. It follows that the results of the die rolls could avoid any terminal pattern forever; the game is therefore not finite.

---

Anton's supposition that, given an upper limit of $k$ rolls in a game, there are $N^k$ possible outcomes is incorrect. There are *at most* $N^k$ possible outcomes; there could be early-termination criteria introduced.

Update: @AntonV. has addressed this by noting you can always pad the end of the game with throwaway rolls. This is true; obviously fairness is preserved under these situations (as the odds of each player's win is unaffected). So their answer works.

Comment: See my comments, following the posting.  You can also have $X = r^k$, where $r$ is a divisor of $N$.

Comment: I agree with @user2661923, it's fairly obvious that a game exists if $X=r^k$, where $r$ is a divisor of $N$. But how do we prove for the rest of the cases? (Obviously, $N=1$ is trivial)

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal In my opinion, the underlying question is: can you prove that there is no finite solution when $X < N$ and $X$ is not a divisor of $N$?

Comment: @user2661923 yes. But what about the cases when $X > N$ and $X \neq r^k$?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Under the assumption that $X < N$, $X$ is not a divisor of $N$ is not *solvable*, you would then have the additional issue, of whether this implies that $X > N, x \neq r^k, r|n$ is **therefore** also not solvable.  I suspect that if the first situation is not solvable, that a proof of general unsolvability can then be constructed.  However, this is simply a suspicion of mine.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal By the way, my previous comments were somewhat careless.  $N = 12, X = 9$ is solvable.

Comment: @user2661923 How did you determine $N=12, X=9$ is solvable?

Comment: @CarterHinsley, Regarding your comment about my answer: If the game ends early (before $k$ rolls), you can always just add random rolls to it, without changing the winner. If rolling 1 and then 2 would mean player 1 wins, but the game could go on for $10$ rolls, you can say that player 1 wins for all rolls (1,2, 5, 2, ....)

Comment: @CarterHinsley $9 = 3^2$.  When you roll the die with $N=12$ faces, construe $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as $A$, $\{5,6,7,8\}$ as $B$, and $\{9,10,11,12\}$ as $C$.  Divide the $9$ people into three groups of $3$.  For each group, roll the die, and one of the $3$ people will win, depending on whether the roll of the die represents $A, B,$ or $C$.  Then, after $3$ rolls, $9$ people have been reduced to $3$ people, and you roll the die one more time.

Comment: @AntonV. Please elaborate on what you mean.  The game must end in a finite number of rolls, and each person must have the exact same probability of winning.  I considered the idea of having (*ghost*) players, which analogizes to a bye, and couldn't make it work.  I also considered ignoring some of the rolls.  However, this violates the constraint that the tournament must end in a finite number of die rolls.

Comment: First of all, let's not think about making it a 'fun' game, if you roll a die 3 times, the game can just be: player 1 wins if the outcome is (1,5,3) or (4,3,1) and so on. Any finite game can be expressed this way. The point is that if the game is ALWAYS finite, there is a maximum length the game can be. You can make every game that length by just adding random rolls to the end of a game that ended early.

Comment: @user2661923 I've added an example to my answer. Note that if we wanted to make the game have a length of 3, each player would need 50 winning rolls instead of 5, so we can say: player 1 wins if the rolls are (0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,0,2),...(0,4,8),(0,4,9), which is the same as saying that player 1 wins if the first 2 rolls are (0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3) and (0,4)

Answer (score 0):

Let us express the number of players under the binomial coefficient form $X=\binom{N}{n}$ which clearly is always possible.

For example, let us assume there are (as many as) $35$ players. Let us take the form:

$$X=\binom{N}{n}=\binom{7}{3}=35$$

These $35$ players can be placed in bijective correspondence with the subsets with 3 elements

$$abc, abd, abe, abf, acd, ace, \cdots def $$

selected from the set $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}.$

Said otherwise, in bijective corresponence with the $7$-digits codes with 3 digits "one":

$$1110000, \ 1101000, \ 1100100, \cdots 0000111.$$

There exists a "sampling" algorithm known as Knuth's algorithm S (The Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2, 3.4.2 p.142), as described [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_algorithm_S) allowing to choose $n$ items from a set of $N$ items, **with equal probability**.

Here is an example with $n=3, N=7$ as above showing the selection of certain subset with code (1010001) [see legend]. with the choosing probabilities given by the $n \times (N-n)=3 \times 4$ array (recall: $n$ is the number of ones and $N-n$ is the number of zeros):

What is the probability of such a path ?

[image]

Fig. 1: Selection of the set of 3 elements with code 1010001 using a shortest path between $A$ and $B$: going upwards = 0 (don'take), going leftward = 1 (take).

The probability of taking such a path is :

$$\frac{\color{blue}{3}}{\color{red}{7}}\times\frac{\color{green}{4}}{\color{red}{6}}\times\frac{\color{blue}{2}}{\color{red}{5}}\times\frac{\color{green}{3}}{\color{red}{4}}\times\frac{\color{green}{2}}{\color{red}{3}}\times\frac{\color{green}{1}}{\color{red}{2}}\times\frac{\color{blue}{1}}{\color{red}{1}}=\frac{\color{blue}{3!}\color{green}{4!}}{\color{red}{7!}}=\frac{1}{\binom{7}{3}}$$

establishing equiprobability because, whatever the ranks of the choices, we must "sweep"

- all values $\color{blue}{3,2,1}$ (horizontal sweep),
- all values $\color{green}{4,3,2,1}$ (vertical sweep), both for the numerators and
- all values $\color{red}{7,6,5,4,3,2,1}$ (oblique sweep) for the denominators ...

This probabilistic graph can be traversed in a dynamical way (i.e., without constructing it beforehand) as shown on the following Matlab program:

> ```
>  n = 3 ; N = 7 ; C = '' ; % C = code to be constructed
>  for p = N:-1:1 ; % please note step -1
>     s = '0';
>     if rand < q/p ; q = q-1 ; s = '1'; end;
>     p = p-1; 
>     C = [C,s];
>  end;
> ```

Important restriction (following a remark by miracle173): The previous program uses a "continuous" random number generator "rand" (uniformly distributed over $[0,1)$). The test "$\operatorname{rand}<q/p$" can be transformed into a rigorous discrete equivalent ; for example, testing if $\operatorname{rand}<3/5$ is equivalent to test whether the result issued from (say) a $15$-sided die is larger than $9$.

In order that such a conversion is possible, a sufficient condition is that the die has $N!$ faces.

Remark: in fact, the die should have $a(N)$ faces where $a(N)$ is defined by this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A003418).

Comment: Assume N=7 and X=34, how do you choose n?

Comment: One [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4451429/11206) already showed that $X|N^K$, so this contradicts  that $X$ and $N$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: @miracle173 I must have a closer look.

Comment: @miracle173 see the remark I have added at the end.

Comment: I must think about your remark. But it is still unclear to me how you choose $n$ if the number of faces of the is $N=7$ and the number of players is $X=34$. Can you explain  this?

Comment: Maybe the fact that the meaning of $N$ in the question and in my answer isn't the same doesn't help the understanding It's sure that the condition I place on the number of faces (being a factorial) is very restrictive.

Comment: I can't see how this answer is related to the problem.  you present a fancy algorithm to select an item from X items with equal  probability using a continuous random generator.  Even if you replace the continuous random generator by a dice with N! faces this is not a useful answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: Why do you use unfriendly terms like "fancy algorithm", "not a useful answer" ? First of all, you should understand that testing whether a continuous random generator is (I take an example) larger that 3/5 is equivalent to test whether the result issued from (say) a 15-sided die is larger than 9.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted  not be unfriendly. I think it is rather easy to see that if the number X of players  divides the number F of faces of the dice to select a player by throwing the  dice: take the result of the dice throw and divide it by X.  And as far as I understand here you show that we can choose a player randomly if we F is a very special multiple of X. So this is  a weaker result that you get by taking a more complicated approach. That is why I think this is not useful. But maybe I miss something.